# Mongodb I can see the size of the collection but, find() does not return anything

Tags: mongodb, learning-locker

I am new to working with Mongo. I recently taken over our LearningLocker database from a previous employee. I can see using show dbs, the database has 4.188GB. But even using a simple db.learninglocker.find() is not returning anything. Any suggestions on how to review the data?

Comment: Add exact steps you've followed and the results of each step to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass down an object as argument to the find function:

`db.learninglocker.find({})`